# Change Win7 Theme to Mac (OSX Lion)

Tags: windows-7, osx, display

**TL:DR** I want to get a look and feel of Mac Lion on my Win7 laptop.

I googled/ youtubed and got some links line [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jtl8Hi4rac), [that](https://skinpacks.com/download/windows-7/mac-os-x-skin-pack/) and so on.

Some of the comments here and there mentions they have virus(es).

Can anybody recommend any theme/skin that I can get installed on my laptop *safely*?

Answer (score 1):

Every antivirus I've used so far has flagged every patcher as a virus. They're known to change how systems work. I'd say its just a false positive as long as you've downloaded it from a good site.

I've used [UXpatcher](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/30994-uxtheme-patch-for-windows-7-sp1/) without any issues in the past. You just have to disable your antivirus while its installing, after that you can reenable.

As for download site, I'd suggest exploring for yourself for a bit. I prefer searching in [deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com). As for your Mac theme (I don't like Mac) [here](http://www.deviantart.com/morelikethis/150208374) it is. Just make sure you read at least some of the comments so you can make an educated guess on whether or not they're safe (they're safe every time I've installed one TBH).